# AccessLogValve - Birt - log posted report parametrs in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, logging, birt, access-log

are there any possibility using tomcat accesslogvalve to log what is posted as parameters to birt under tomcat.
 Using standard pattern dont give me results. the expected result i wanted is with what user post as parameters with this report

actual tested accesslog valve conf  :

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"  
               prefix="Mifos-Server-access_log." suffix=".txt" pattern="%{x-Forwarded-For}i %l %a %A %H %m %q %r %S %t %u %U %T   %{Cookie}i" resolveHosts="false"/>
```

result :

```
10.10.10.5 10.10.10.10 HTTP/1.1 GET ?__report=/home/myapp/report/pay_rest.rptdesign&reportName=pay_dorig%20source&userId=123&__format=pdf GET /myapp/birtReports?__report=/home/myapp/report/pay_rest&reportName=pay_dorig%20source&userId=123&__format=pdf HTTP/1.1 43E36E8R248ECEFB4B5AX985975FNEU7 [13/Jan/2015:12:30:41 +0100] - /my_app/birtReports 2.224
```

thanks

Comment: take a look at [this](http://www.birt-exchange.org/org/forum/index.php/topic/28375-can-i-use-cookies-to-recall-user-selected-parameters-from-last-visit/) does it give you cause to modify your question?

Comment: thanks, but that's not what i am searching for :)